# Add variable number of fields to a database table with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I can't seem to come up with a proper way to add a variable number of fields to a database table. Let's say that I'm building a web app where visitors can sign up and manage their contacts. They can add individual contacts through a form, which has the following text input fields:

- Contact name
- Phone number
- E-mail address
- Company
- Address
- Homepage

In this form, only the 'contact name' field is required, so it's perfectly possible to add a contact's e-mail address without knowing his or her phone number. How can i properly implement this in PHP?

They way I've done it before involves iterating over the $_POST array and checking if each particular field has been submitted. If a field has been submitted, its field name gets added to the SQL statement. Then we do the same for the values.

My gut feeling is telling me that this way of working is horribly wrong, but I can't think of any other way to do it...

```
function generateSQLStatement($_POST) {

    // Add field names to SQL statement
    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $sql .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    // Remove last comma and space
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);

    // Add values to SQL statement
    $sql .= ') VALUES (';
    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $sql .= $value . ', ';
        }
    }

    // Remove last comma and space
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);

    $sql .= ')';

    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Look into [active record patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). I used to do it the way you're doing it now, but modelling each table's columns as object classes makes it way easier to deal with. Fewer bugs too.

Comment: I really do hope that you are sanitizing those posted values...

Comment: nothing particularly wrong with the current approach. i would not rely on the post names for the db field names, i would have an array for those, but still looping to see if they are filled in is fine. Its not really a variable number of fields, the fields are fixed, its just some are empty (pretty normal stuff). submitting empty ones wont hurt

Comment: Input values always get validated and then sanitized, but I didn't include these steps in my code because it has nothing to do with the question itself. Still thanks for pointing out that user input should always be validated (and possibly sanitized).

Answer (score 3):

Note that in the code below `SANITIZE_ME` is a placeholder for a method such as [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or whatever is suitable in your situation.  You will need to adapt this answer as appropriate.

```
function generateSQLStatement($_POST) {

    $fieldNames = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            if (!empty($fieldNames)) {
                $fieldNames .= ',';
                $values .= ',';
            }
            $fieldNames .= SANITIZE_ME($field);
            $values .= "'" . SANITIZE_ME($value) . "'";

        }
    }

    return "($fieldNames) VALUES ($values)";
}
```

This approach uses only one loop, so is faster.  But you probably want to validate your field names against a predefined array of acceptable fields, just in case someone edits the form that's posting to your script and puts in an invalid field name.

**EDIT**

A more generalized approach can be used to create a utility function that you can reuse easily with other tables throughout your application:

*This lot can go in some generic include file:*

```
// An array whose keys are valid table names and
// whose values are arrays of valid field names
// within the table named in the key
$acceptableFields = array(
    'contacts' => array(
        // valid fields in the 'contacts' table
        'name', 'address' //...
    )
    // ... other mappings, if desired
);

function isValidField($table, $field) {
    if (!isset($acceptableFields[$table]))
        return false;

    return in_array($field, $acceptableFields[$table]); 
    // Note that in_array is case-sensitive, so you may want 
    // to just manually loop through $acceptableFields[$table]
    // and compare strings yourself.
}

function insertData($table, array $fieldValuesMap, mysqli $mysqli) {
    // First, some self-explanatory validation:
    if ($table === null)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$table cannot be null');

    if (!is_string($table))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$table must be a String');

    if (empty($table))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$table cannot be an empty String');

    if (!isset($acceptableFields[$table]))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("\"$table\" is an invalid table name");

    $fieldNames = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach ($fieldValuesMap as $field => $value) {
        // check the field name is valid for the given table
        // and that the value is not empty.  You may want to
        // add a logging mechanism for invalid field names to
        // help track bugs or even malicious use
        if (isValidField($table, $field) && !empty($value)) {
            // check to see whether there are any items in 
            // the lists already
            if (!empty($fieldNames)) {
                // yes, so add commas:
                $fieldNames .= ',';
                $values .= ',';
            }

            // no need to escape the field name as we have already
            // checked that it is valid
            $fieldNames .= $field;
            // but we do need to escape the value
            $values .= "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        }
    }

    // check whether we've actually got anything to insert:
    if (empty($fieldNames))
        return NULL;

    return $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO $table ($fieldNames) VALUES ($values)");
}
```

*An example usage on a page to add Contacts:*

```
require_once "above.file"; // whatever it's called

if ($_POST) {

    $mysqli = new MySQLi(/*...*/);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        // handle connection error
    } else {
        // set your charset
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); // or whatever you use

        $result = insertData('contacts', $_POST, $mysqli);

        if ($result === NULL) {
            // There was nothing to insert
        } elseif ($result === FALSE) {
            // An error occurred, handle it here
        } else {
            // Success!  Use $mysqli->insert_id to get your new 
            // record's ID (if appropriate).
        }
    }

}
//
//==============================================
```

A little extra work and you end up with something that is flexible and reusable.  Personally, though, I prefer a more object-oriented (active record) approach.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You could also consider the option of simply inserting the empty fields as well.

Comment: @FranciscoO. Yes, I considered just inserting empty strings, but then thought the OP may be relying on NULL values (or other default values specified in the DB schema) in these fields when reading them elsewhere in his app.

Comment: My application does rely on NULL values, so empty strings are no option.